# How to push data from local server to iPad - No APN, No Internet Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, push, lan

Is there a way to push data from local server (hosted on intranet) to an iPad application without internet connection? The app is supposed to work only on LAN over wifi. Apple Push Notification is out of picture as internet connection is not available.
However the app will be running on both the devices all the time.

The model, I am talking about, is something like this:

Devices: Local Server - Wifi Connection - iPad1, iPad2

iPad1 updates some data on local server over wifi... Server needs to notify iPad2 about the change over Wifi.

Thank You!

Comment: Without APN there is no way to Notify directly iPad2 about changes that are made by iPad 1. what you can do is to play some kind of trick that when application launches it checks for any update that is made by iPad1 to the server, and the server will respond accordingly

Comment: You will have to write this logic yourself.  On a high level, it will involve notifying the server, and having the server open a socket connection to the iOS device and then writing to it whenever there is a change.

Comment: See bluetooth chatting that can help you as you need no internet connection.

Comment: You might want to check out Ray Wenderlich's tutorial, "How To Create A Socket Based iPhone App and Server".

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Because if we want to deliver a notification, it will have to deliver to   the APN server(which have the responsibility to send notifications to the device). So in the case of no internet connection it is impossible.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use use Local Notification instead of Push Notification.May be it will helpful to you.

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Comment: he wants notification from server. local notification only works within the device

Comment: Please read more carefully the question, he needs to deliver messages in a local network.